# Connection timeout when using Linux box as gateway to share VPN

Tags: networking, iptables, nordvpn

I am trying to setup Linux machine (192.168.1.47) as a gateway so that I can share VPN connection with another machine (192.168.1.12). Both of the machines are Ubuntu VirtualBox VMs setup on different machines (bridged connection). I have the following setup but I cannot access most websites.

**Gateway Machine**:

```
root@pi:~# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  unn-89-187-175-12.cdn77.com  anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  192.168.1.0/24       anywhere

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
NFLOG      all  --  anywhere             anywhere             nflog-group 6
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             unn-89-187-175-12.cdn77.com
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             192.168.1.0/24
```

---

```
root@pi:~# iptables -L -t nat
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

---

```
root@pi:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.5.0.2        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 nordlynx
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 enp0s3
128.0.0.0       10.5.0.2        128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 nordlynx
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 enp0s3
```

**Client:**

```
root@piclient:~# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.47    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 enp0s3
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp0s3
```

From the client machine, **I an reach example.com and icanhazip.com but can't reach google.com and other websites** (curl: connection timeout with ipv4). Even ping to 8.8.8.8 works fine. Using the nflog I can see the traffic which is successfully being sent across the gateway machine (mostly DNS/ping). As you can see below client is able to resolve google.com but I don't see follow-up TCP request like it does with example.com.

```
root@pi:~# tcpdump -s 0 -n -i nflog:6
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on nflog:6, link-type NFLOG (Linux netfilter log messages), capture size 262144 bytes
16:26:51.578039 IP 192.168.1.12.50342 > 8.8.8.8.53: 56494+ A? google.com. (28)
16:26:51.578135 IP 8.8.8.8.53 > 192.168.1.12.50342: 56494 6/13/10 A 173.194.199.101, A 173.194.199.102, A 173.194.199.113, A 173.194.199.139, A 173.194.199.138, A 173.194.199.100 (508)
```

- What can I do to debug further?
- Is it possible the router (192.168.1.1) or the host machines of the VMs are interfering? If so, why does it not interfere with example.com?

Comment: If you try this (to work around "PMTUD blackhole" issues),  does it help? `iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS --set-mss 1420` ?

Comment: That didn't work. I think it's issue of host machines :/